# Are level and card color counted in combat calculations?

Tags: ios, injustice-gods-among-us

In Injustice for **iOS**, are any of the combat calculations affected directly by card color/quality (bronze, silver, gold, as well as elite status) and card level, or are those things only important because they contribute to the final attack/health of a card?

That is, are two cards with the same attack/health equal, regardless of if one happens to be a level 25 gold card and the other is a level 15 Elite III silver, or some other mismatch? Do these factors contribute to any other calculation during gameplay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I don't think so. They purely contribute to the attack/health of a card. You win/lose based on your strategic offense/defense techniques.

I have defeated gold cards with silver elites. It can be tough, but the level of combat is not affected by the cards involved in combat.

Hope this answers your question!